# Difference between defining a function inside versus outside of another function

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I have written a function `derivative(w1, w2, pt)` that evaluates the derivative of the function `f(x) = w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1` at point `pt`. Strangely, I have found that I get different results depending on whether `def f(x)` is positioned inside or outside of `derivative(w1, w2, pt)`.  Why does the positioning of `def f(x)` matter / which is correct?

Example 1:

```
def derivative(w1, w2, pt):
    x = sy.Symbol('x')

    def f(x):
        return w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1

    # Get derivative of f(x)
    def df(x):
        return sy.diff(f(x),x)

    # Evaluate at point x
    return df(x).subs(x,pt)
```

From which `derivative(5, 8, 2)` returns `68`.

Example 2:

```
def f(x):
    return w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1

def derivative(w1, w2, pt):
    x = sy.Symbol('x')

    # Get derivative of f(x)
    def df(x):
        return sy.diff(f(x),x)

    # Evaluate at point x
    return df(x).subs(x,pt)
```

From which `derivative(5, 8, 2)` returns `53`.

Comment: I appreciate the link - but I do think this question is different because I understand why people nest functions for readability but I don't understand here why the nesting order affects the outcome of the function

Comment: I'm surprised example 2 works at all - in example 1 `w1` and `w2` are available inside `f` because they're closed over from `derivative`'s parameters, but they don't exist in example 2. I guess `sy.diff` is doing some magic that's being interfered with.

Comment: Can you add import statements to your code so that it's a minimal working example and can be tested by others?

Comment: @johnrsharpe That's what had me confused - if the difference in output was due to scope example 2 shouldn't work at all

Comment: @c0deBr0 your second example only work by accident - you tested it in a context where `w1` and `w2` where defined as global variables. Copy it to a .py file (without other definitions) and try to execute it and you'll get a NameError.

Comment: @c0deBr0 also the answers to the dup question DO answer your own - nested functions are not that much about readability but about scope and closures.

Comment: ask yourself: which ‘w2’ is f(x) seeing in your global? in your nested?  practical effects got nothing to do w readability.

Comment: @Harpe: `import sympy as sy`

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes you're right, thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's your global scope that is polluted. Look at this example :

```
import sympy as sy

def f(x, w1, w2):
    return w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1

def derivative(w1, w2, pt):
    x = sy.Symbol('x')

    # Get derivative of f(x)
    def df(x, w1, w2):
        return sy.diff(f(x, w1, w2),x)

    # Evaluate at point x
    return df(x, w1, w2).subs(x,pt)

print(derivative(5, 8, 2))
```

This is just a modified version of your example 2 and it returns the same answer.

Comment: Yes I see what you mean thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A nested function has access to the local names in the parent function. When you define `f` *outside*, it can't access the locals `w1` and `w2`, so it'll have to assume those are *globals* instead.

And if you don't define `w1` and `w2` at the global level, your second version actually raises a `NameError`:

```
>>> import sympy as sy
>>> def f(x):
...     return w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1
...
>>> def derivative(w1, w2, pt):
...     x = sy.Symbol('x')
...     def df(x):
...         return sy.diff(f(x),x)
...     return df(x).subs(x,pt)
...
>>> derivative(5, 8, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in derivative
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in df
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in f
NameError: name 'w1' is not defined
```

That you didn't get an exception means you *already* defined `w1` and `w2` before, and it is *those values* that are being used to provide your incorrect answer.

You can 'fix' your second example by setting `w1` and `w2` as globals instead. It doesn't actually matter what you pass in as the first and second arguments to the `derivative()` call, because those `w1` and `w2` argument values are *entirely ignored*:

```
>>> w1 = 5
>>> w2 = 8
>>> derivative('This value is ignored', 'And so is this one', 2)
68
```

In your local setup, you *probably* set `w1` and `w2` to `4` and `5`, respectively, because it is those values for which `x` is `53`:

```
>>> w1 = 4
>>> w2 = 5
>>> derivative('This value is ignored', 'And so is this one', 2)
53
```

For your first example, `w1` and `w2` are provided by the locals in `derivative()`; it doesn't matter what global names you may have defined, those are not going to be used instead.

If you want to define `f` outside of `derivative()`, and still pass in `w1` and `w2` to `derivative()` first, then you also need to pass those same values on to the `f()` function:

```
def f(x, w1, w2):
    return w1 * x**3 + w2 * x - 1

def derivative(w1, w2, pt):
    x = sy.Symbol('x')

    # Get derivative of f(x, w1, w2)
    def df(x):
        return sy.diff(f(x, w1, w2), x)

    # Evaluate at point x
    return df(x).subs(x,pt)
```

Now `f()` explicitly receives `w1` and `w2` from the nested `df()` function, and not from globals.